# Why isn't there any method to solve integral, like differentiation has?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals, differential

Differentiation of function has a method to solve, by limits

$$ \frac{d(f(x))}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Is there any method by which we can solve integral without using antiderivative, like differentiation does?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus as the definition of an integral. The actual definition of the (Riemann) integral is a limit of sums.

Comment: Riemann integrals certainly has a definition using areas of partitions

Comment: But we can't integrate directly, like integral of (1+sin²x)^1/2.dx, but we can differentiate using limit formula.

Comment: You can add the sums directly to get an approximation, that by choosing the width of your rectangles and adding more and more terms, can get arbitrarily close to the true area under the curve. No antiderivatives involved in this procedure. In this sense it is analogous to approximating the derivative by taking the limit for a small h and getting your approximations better and better for smaller and smaller h.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262397/functions-with-no-closed-form-derivative

Comment: @Alborz Can you give me a example like integral of sinx.dx by this method? Because I don't know how will I calculate $$\lim_{h\to 0} h(\sum sinx)$$ where upper and lower limit are also not known

Comment: @Siddharth A rigorous definition is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral. This is the definition that is taught in real analysis; in most introductory calculus courses, it is done with areas of trapezoids: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: *Can you give me a example like integral of sinx.dx by this method?* --- See [Computing $\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \; dx$ using the definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/738574/13130)

Comment: Thanks to all, I got it!

Comment: Similar question: [Is there a formal definition for antiderivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317753/is-there-a-formal-definition-for-antiderivatives)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no".  There is no mechanical way to integrate generally.  Additionally, you will find that there are a lot of "basic" integrals that have no symbolic solutions.  (Note that, technically, anything has a symbolic solution if you simply define a new symbol.  However, integration doesn't have any closed set like differentiation does.)

Example: $\int \cos(x^2)\,dx$ does not have a solution, except by introducing a new symbol to represent its results (and, in fact, the "fresnel integral" function is often used for that one).

In mathematics, not everything can be mechanically determined.  This comes as a surprise to many, but it is a fact of mathematics.

Comment: As you said "fresnel integral", this too have been solved or proved by basic defination or using other integral or either should have its own definition. Right?

Comment: @Siddharth No. We can evaluate this integral over, say, $(0,\infty)$, but not in general. There's more to integration than finding antiderivatives, but we know for sure there are plenty of functions for which no "elementary" (=nice) antiderivative can be found

Comment: It has a power series expansion, but nothing "great" in my eyes. There's not always a clean closed form for expressions - a fact one should accept when studying mathematics.

Comment: Oh! Yes I have got it now on the Wikipedia.

Comment: @Siddharth What I always tell my class is that, there is nothing nonsensical about finding the area under $\cos(x^2)$, but that doesn't mean there is a function for it.  However, we can define whatever function we wish.  So, if the area under $\cos(x^2)$ is a sensical idea, then I can simply define a function, $Q(x)$, where $Q(x) = \int \cos(x^2)\,dx$.  A lot of math is done this way - simply identifying pieces of interest is a step forward.